# Причина - Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException?

Tags: java, исключения

подскажите пожалуйста, почему вылезает:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException?

```
package com.jdbc;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Driver;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;


public abstract class Main {
    private static final String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC";
    private static final String LoginName = "root";
    private  static final String Password = "rootroot";

    public  Main() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        Connection connection = null;
        Driver driver = new FabricMySQLDriver ( );
        try {
            DriverManager.registerDriver(driver);
        }
        catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println ("Не удалось зарегистрировать драйвер!");
            return;
        }
        try {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, LoginName, Password);
            System.out.println("code");
        }
        catch (SQLException ex){
            System.out.println("Не удалось создать соединение!");

        }
        finally {
            if (connection !=null) {
                connection.close ();
            }
        }
              executeUpdate();
            createCustomerTable();

    }

    private static void executeUpdate() {
    }


    public static void executeUpdate(String query) throws SQLException {
        Connection connection = null;
        assert false;
        Statement statement = getStatement (connection);
        /* Для Insert, Update, Delete */
        statement.executeUpdate (query);
    }

    private static Statement getStatement(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
        return connection.createStatement ( );
    }


    private static void createCustomerTable() throws SQLException {
        String customerTableQuery = "CREATE TABLE customers " +
                "(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT, age INTEGER)";
        String customerEntryQuery = "INSERT INTO customers " +
                "VALUES (73, 'Brian', 33)";
        executeUpdate (customerTableQuery);
        executeUpdate (customerEntryQuery);
    }

}
```

Comment: В какой строчке оно происходит?

Comment: вот в этих - private static Statement getStatement(Connection connection) throws SQLException {    return connection.createStatement ( );

Comment: Потому что Connection connection = null;
        assert false;
        Statement statement = getStatement (connection);

Comment: Передаёте null и обращаетесь к методу

Comment: А на что поменять Connection connection = ?

Comment: На что ото вроде connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, LoginName ...

Comment: так теперь выпадает- Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException  при замене null на Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, LoginName, Password);

Comment: Добавил ответ. Посмотрите пожалуйста на само соединение верно ли оно и есть ли соединение

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Измените немного тут, при условии что соединение возможно и верна авторизация

```
 public static void executeUpdate(String query) throws SQLException {
    Connection connection = null;
    try {
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, LoginName, Password);
        Statement statement = getStatement (connection);
        /* Для Insert, Update, Delete */
        statement.executeUpdate (query);
    }
    catch (SQLException ex){
        System.out.println("Не удалось создать соединение!");

    }
    
}
```

Comment: Сейчас результат получился такой- Не удалось создать соединение!
Не удалось создать соединение!
Не удалось создать соединение!

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: Не могу понять, создается ли таблица у меня)

Comment: Посмотрите на соединение и поправьте url логин пароль

Comment: Попробуйте так jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql в url

Comment: Таблица не создастся потому что соединения нет

Comment: с url jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql  такой же результат выдает(

Comment: Как называется база данных? Она есть вообще и есть ли такой пользователь с паролем

Comment: Сейчас вот так: code
Не удалось создать соединение!
Не удалось создать соединение!

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: Да, в Воркбенч у меня такие же пароль и логин, а база называется- usersdb

Comment: Так напишите jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/usersdb?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC

Comment: )) теперь у меня - code

Process finished with exit code 0
вроде бы все ок, но таблица у меня точно создается?)

Comment: Я думаю что помог вам с поставленным вопросом далее уже другой вопрос

Comment: Спасибо большое!)

Comment: А таблица и запись должны быть. Если ничего не напутали

Comment: Пометить ответ не забудьте если помог

Comment: Я только зарегистрировалась здесь, с текущим статусом при оценке ответа вылезает сообщение- "Спасибо за отзыв! Голоса от участников с репутацией менее 15 учитываются, но не меняют публично отображаемое значение рейтинга."        А так, я оценила его)

Comment: Не голосовать а принять как полезный. Под стрелками

Comment: Готово, спасибо)